# How do I get this Capistrano task to run on the server instead of locally?

Tags: ruby, shell, ssh, capistrano

I want to pull the last modified file from a directory. This capistrano task works locally just fine, but how do I make this run on the server so I can pull the servers data?

```
namespace :pull do
  desc "Hello Pull data from the server"
  task :hello, roles: :db do
    ## Want this to return what's on the server. Not locally.
    puts "Getting filename of last created database backup"
    db_backups_directory_path = "/home/deployer/backups"
    last_db_backup_archived = Dir.glob(File.join(db_backups_directory_path, '*')).
                              select  {|f| File.file? f }.
                              sort_by {|f| File.mtime f }.
                              last
    puts last_db_backup_archived
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd just go with `run`.  Capistrano executes *commands* in parallel over a bunch of servers, so you'll have to translate your ruby into shell code. Thankfully, in your case it's more or less a straightforward translation.

```
task :hello, roles: :db do
  ## Want this to return what's on the server. Not locally.
  puts "Getting filename of last created database backup"
  db_backups_directory_path = "/home/deployer/backups"
  run <<-CMD
     find #{db_backups_directory_path} -type f -printf '%A@ %p\n'|
     sort -n | tail -n1 | cut -d" "  -f2
  CMD
end
```

Answer (score 1):

The `capture` command will also run on a remote server. In addition to running a command remotely, it can write the stdout of the command to a ruby variable. So you could manipulate it with ruby methods, and then pass it back in with

```
some_variable = capture ("pwd")
capture ("cd #{some_variable}/.. && ls -alh")
```

This isn't the best example, but you get the general idea. The second `capture` is obviously not necessary, and you could substitute it with `run` and it wouldn't make a difference.

However, you should know that this will not work if you are running this task against multiple servers.

From the documentation:

> Executes the given command on the first server targetted by the
>   current task, collects it's stdout into a string, and returns the
>   string. The command is invoked via #invoke_command.
>
> http://rdoc.info/github/capistrano/capistrano/Capistrano/Configuration/Actions/Inspect#capture-instance_method